# Counting occurrences of dynamic strings in TXT / Powershell

Tags: powershell, counting

I have a TXT containing 350.000 URL paths. I want to count the distinct occurrences of a string that is included in the path. I don't know in advance the strings. I just know that it comes in 2nd place of the path.

The paths looks like this:

images/STRINGA/2XXXXXXXX_rTTTTw_GGGG1_Top_MMM1_YY02_ZZZ30_AAAA5.jpg
images/STRINGA/3XXXXXXXX_rTTTTw_GGGG1_Top_MMM1_YY02_ZZZ30_AAAA5.jpg
images/STRINGB/4XXXXXXXX_rTTTTw_GGGG1_Top_MMM1_YY02_ZZZ30_AAAA5.jpg
images/STRINGB/5XXXXXXXX_rTTTTw_GGGG1_Top_MMM1_YY02_ZZZ30_AAAA5.jpg
images/STRINGC/5XXXXXXXX_rTTTTw_GGGG1_Top_MMM1_YY02_ZZZ30_AAAA5.jpg

So I split the path with  $searchstring= $item.Split("/")[1].
Now I can iterate through all the lines in the TXT extracting the string.
But how can I make a final document looking like this:
STRINGA;2
STRINGB;2
STRINGC;1

How can I dynamically extract a string and then search its occurrences? I need just a hint, I can get the rest working then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Group-Object` command:

```
Get-Content path\to\urls.txt |Group-Object { $_.Split('/')[1] } -NoElement |Select-Object @{Name='String';Expression='Name'},Count |Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Works like charm, thank you awesome man in a black hoodie somewhere in the world ;)

Comment: You would get 10 extra bonus points if you could give me a hint how I can make a a progress bar. I looked up write-progress, but it seems that that all operations only working in simple processes. Can I wrap a progress bar around my foreach $item in $list ?So I have a better feeling where it is

Comment: Ah forget it, found it :-)